# before_save, strip a string

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, before-filter, before-save

I'm trying to `strip` the whitespaces of the variable `Username` in my User Model.

I'm using

```
before_save do
  self.username.strip!
end
```

but it doesn't seem to work, am i missing something ?

Comment: You're missing the assignment `self.username = self.username.strip!`

Comment: @Hitham S. AlQadheeb, There is no need for the assignment. using `strip!` already do that.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

You'd rather update the setter instead of polluting your model with callbacks:

```
def username=(value)
  self[:username] = value.to_s.strip
end
```

Btw, I prefer [`squish`](http://apidock.com/rails/String/squish)

Comment: Thanks for answering, it worked just fine. Can you explain to me why you prefer squish over strip?

Comment: squish removes all silly blanks, strip only removes leading and trailing

Comment: Sounds cool, so i replace value.to_s.strip => value.to_s.squish right ?

Comment: @daniel this was to avoid the `nil` possibility

Comment: please use `super(value.to_s.strip)` instead of `self[:attr] = value.to_s.strip` if it's ActiveRecord

Answer (score 0):

If you want to remove **only leading and trailing** white space you can use .strip!

But as you said:

> I'm trying to strip the whitespaces of the variable Username in my
>   User Model.

I think actually you want to **remove all spaces**  following should do:

`.gsub(/\s+/, "")`

**EDIT:**

Oh yes, You can also use Rail's built-in method [`squish()`](http://apidock.com/rails/String/squish)

thanx to *apneadiving* for reminding